# vertical menu modx

Tags: menu, modx-revolution

i am very new to modx and i want to make a side menu.
The menu has 2 levels.
for example the file tree is:
**first category**
--park
--hospital
...etc
**second category**
--houses
--roofs
..etc

here is the thing. i use the wayfinder snippet to view the menu
[[!Wayfinder? &startId=`0` &outerClass=`nav nav-list` &level=`0`]]
but what i really want is to have the top level links as headers and not as links.

Any ideas?
To be specific i want to make a bootstrap based nav-list menu or something similar.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the wayfinder docs - about 2/3 way down the page there are the options for changing the output templates... I believe it's &parentRowTpl  that you want to use, just create a template that makes the top level item a heading instead of a link. (don't forget the [wf.wrapper] to get your sub menu ;) )

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.modxcms.com/index.php/Accordion_menu_with_Wayfinder - Here is an example of the vertical menu for Evolution, but for Revolution there no changes are necessary, all the same. And the second example for Revolution - http://creativedev.in/2012/10/accordion-menu-with-modx/